# Genesis 6:3, 120 Years

Tags: genesis

Could the word “years” be an error in translation but instead be the word Jobel, the prefix to the word Jubilee as some students claim?

Genesis 6:3 KJV

> And the LORD said, My spirit shall not always strive with man, for that he also is flesh: yet his days shall be an hundred and twenty **years**.

Comment: "some students claim?" - What students? Please [edit] your question to supply a reference for this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what "Jobel" is referring to.

Here's the Hebrew:

- ”וַיֹּ֣אמֶר יְהוָ֗ה לֹֽא־יָד֨וֹן רוּחִ֤י בָֽאָדָם֙ לְעֹלָ֔ם בְּשַׁגַּ֖ם ה֣וּא בָשָׂ֑ר וְהָי֣וּ יָמָ֔יו מֵאָ֥ה וְעֶשְׂרִ֖ים שָׁנָֽה“ (Genesis 6:3 HMT-W4)
- "And the Lord said, 'My spirit will not put up with mankind forever since he is especially corrupt. His days are/will be 120 years."

The word for years (שָׁנָֽה) is very clear. And the word is used over 800 times in the OT. So that word is not in doubt at all.

So, "years" is definitely not an error.